# Assembly comparing numbers

Tags: assembly, tasm

I am using TASM MS-DOS to create a game where the user has to solve mathematical problems. I have managed to create a procedure that prints an exercise on the screen and lets the user type an answer. However, when I try to compare the user's answer and the correct answer, it always says that the user was wrong. Here is my code:

```
proc getInput
    
    READ:
    MOV AH, 1
    INT 21H
    
    CMP AL, 13
    JE ENDOFNUMBER
    
    MOV VALUE, AL
    SUB VALUE, 48
    
    MOV AL, [userAnswer]
    MOV BL, 10
    MUL BL
    
    ADD AL, VALUE
    
    MOV [userAnswer], AL
    
    JMP READ

    ENDOFNUMBER:   

    ret
endp getInput

proc Addition
addition:
    call AddBreakLines
    call AddSpaces
    call generateBasicRandomNumber
    mov dl, [randomNumber]
    mov [basicRandomNumber1], dl  
    add  dl, '0'  
    mov ah, 2h  
    int 21h
    mov dx, offset plusSign
    call printStr
    push 1
    call sleep
    call generateBasicRandomNumber
    mov dl, [randomNumber]
    mov [basicRandomNumber2], dl
    add  dl, '0'  
    mov ah, 2h  
    int 21h
    push 1
    call sleep
    ;
    mov dl, [space]
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h
    push 1
    call sleep
    mov dl, [equalSign]
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h
    push 1
    call sleep
    mov dl, [space]
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h
    ;
    call getInput
    mov al, [basicRandomNumber1]
    add al, [basicRandomNumber2]
    mov [result], al
    
    call CompareResultWithUserAnswer
    ;call CompareResultWithUserAnswer
    call printNewLine
    call printNewLine
    call printNewLine
    cmp [isCorrect], 0
    je INCORRECT_ADDITION
    CORRECT_ADDITION:
    mov dx, offset correctMsg
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    jmp END_ADDITION_FUNCTION
    
    INCORRECT_ADDITION:

    mov dx, offset incorrectMsg
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    END_ADDITION_FUNCTION:
    jmp END_ADDITION
    ret
endp Addition

proc CompareResultWithUserAnswer
    mov al, [userAnswer]
    cmp al, [result]
    jne NOT_CORRECT
    mov [isCorrect], 1
    jmp END_COMPARE
    NOT_CORRECT:
    mov [isCorrect], 0
    END_COMPARE:
    ret
endp CompareResultWithUserAnswer

proc generateBasicRandomNumber
     mov ax, 40h
     mov es, ax
     mov ax, [es:6Ch]
     and al, 00000111b
     mov [randomNumber], al
     ret
endp generateBasicRandomNumber
```

Comment: Well, what are the actual values that you end up comparing? Check in a debugger or by printing the bytes.

Comment: For one thing you don't seem to reset `userAnswer` to zero before calling `getInput`.

Comment: Definition of `sleep` is missing from the example.